# Replicate same data set under different names

Tags: r

I have a data set say X, simply I want to replicate X  10 times i.e X1,X2,X3.....X10 then write these data sets to my hard drive. In case you wonder why--  This is an intermediate step in which i want to replicate the same analysis 10 times.Any idea how to do that in R?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean "replicate"? is X a dataframe and you want a new dataframe with the rows of X repeated 10 times? is X a dataframe and you want to save X and have the same file repeated 10 times? (Then why not copy/paste it 10 times?) Or do you simply want to create 10 variables called X1,X2, ... X10 in your workspace and (say) `save(X1, X2, ..., X10, file='foobar.rda')`?

Comment: X is a data frame and i want to make 10 copes of it-- thanks

Comment: `for (i in 1:10) assign(paste0('X',i), X)`

Comment: Although what @rawr says is technically what you want, there are much better ways to do what you want. If you want to run many analyses on a single dataset, try showing us the analysis you want to do, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: I am using array of Jobs in a cluster, in which i am applying several Bays methods. I tried parallel and for loops but as you might know bays methods takes time which is big limitation considering the number of combinations that i want to try, I think rawr idea might work for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on rawr comment,  here is the answer:

```
       xx<-matrix((rnorm(10*10)),nco=10,nrow=10) ## matrix 

       for( i in 1:10){
       write.csv(xx,paste("data_", i,".csv",sep=""))}
```